# Adding the values of a hash key together, to ouput a single integer

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm currently doing `exercism.io` and I'm on the Hamming challenge, I'm kind of stuck at this point because what I need to do is add the numbers that occur from the hash together.

The challenge is as follows:

Write a program that can calculate the Hamming difference between two DNA strands.

What they start you off with is this (don't worry about the methods that say `skip`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
gem 'minitest', '>= 5.0.0'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'hamming'

# Test data version:
# ab84334 Merge pull request #106 from bennn/grep-meta

class HammingTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_identical_strands
    assert_equal 0, Hamming.compute('A', 'A')
  end

  def test_long_identical_strands
    assert_equal 0, Hamming.compute('GGACTGA', 'GGACTGA')
  end

  def test_complete_distance_in_single_nucleotide_strands
    assert_equal 1, Hamming.compute('A', 'G')
  end

  def test_complete_distance_in_small_strands
    assert_equal 2, Hamming.compute('AG', 'CT')
  end

  def test_small_distance_in_small_strands
    skip
    assert_equal 1, Hamming.compute('AT', 'CT')
  end

  def test_small_distance
    skip
    assert_equal 1, Hamming.compute('GGACG', 'GGTCG')
  end

  def test_small_distance_in_long_strands
    skip
    assert_equal 2, Hamming.compute('ACCAGGG', 'ACTATGG')
  end

  def test_non_unique_character_in_first_strand
    skip
    assert_equal 1, Hamming.compute('AGA', 'AGG')
  end

  def test_non_unique_character_in_second_strand
    skip
    assert_equal 1, Hamming.compute('AGG', 'AGA')
  end

  def test_large_distance
    skip
    assert_equal 4, Hamming.compute('GATACA', 'GCATAA')
  end

  def test_large_distance_in_off_by_one_strand
    skip
    assert_equal 9, Hamming.compute('GGACGGATTCTG', 'AGGACGGATTCT')
  end

  def test_empty_strands
    skip
    assert_equal 0, Hamming.compute('', '')
  end

  def test_disallow_first_strand_longer
    skip
    assert_raises(ArgumentError) { Hamming.compute('AATG', 'AAA') }
  end

  def test_disallow_second_strand_longer
    skip
    assert_raises(ArgumentError) { Hamming.compute('ATA', 'AGTG') }
  end

  # Problems in exercism evolve over time,
  # as we find better ways to ask questions.
  # The version number refers to the version of the problem you solved,
  # not your solution.
  #
  # Define a constant named VERSION inside of Hamming.
  # If you are curious, read more about constants on RubyDoc:
  # http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html
  def test_bookkeeping
    skip
    assert_equal 1, Hamming::VERSION
  end
end
```

I've successfully done four of them with the following code:

```
class Hamming
  def self.compute(x, y)
    if x == y
      0
    else
      strings = x, y
      joined = strings.join
      positions = (0...joined.length).group_by{|i| joined[i]}
      length = strings.first.length
      n = strings.length
      diff = Hash[*positions.map{|k, v| 
      [k, v.group_by{|i| i % length}.reject{|i, is| is.length == n}.keys]}]
      diff
    end
  end
end
```

What I need to do now is add the digits that are the `value` of the `key` together to create a single integer, for example for this:

```
 10) Failure:
HammingTest#test_complete_distance_in_small_strands [hamming_test.rb:23]:
Expected: 2
  Actual: nil
  #<= {["A", [0]]=>["G", [1]], ["C", [0]]=>["T", [1]]}
```

So what I need to do is add the value of `G` and of `T` together and output a single integer `2`

Question being, how do I add two values together and output a single integer without outputting the entire hash itself?

Comment: Calculating the hamming distance is far easier than you thought. I did it in 2 lines of code.

Comment: The answer for each test case is the number of differences between the two strings provided. And if the lengths of the two strings don't match, it should be an error. Index position of each of the letters is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your hash,

```
h = {["A", [0]]=>["G", [1]], ["C", [0]]=>["T", [1]]}
```

First use [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values) to get out the values.

```
> h.values
 => [["G", [1]], ["T", [1]]]
```

These are arrays, and you want the last entry of each, which [`Array#last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-last) provides.

```
> h.values.map(&:last)
 => [[1], [1]]
```

Your numbers are wrapped in another array, so you could use `last` again, but [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) is semantically nice.

```
> h.values.map(&:last).flatten
 => [1, 1]
```

Then a simple way to sum them is with [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

```
> h.values.map(&:last).flatten.inject(:+)
 => 2
```

It's not clear to me whether you want the numbers out of your hash keys as well, but if you do, you can get them with [Hash#keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-keys), or since you want everything, [`Hash#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_a).

```
> h.keys + h.values
 => [["A", [0]], ["C", [0]], ["G", [1]], ["T", [1]]]
> h.to_a
 => [[["A", [0]], ["G", [1]]], [["C", [0]], ["T", [1]]]]
```

Comment: It's always so simple when it's right in front of you like that lol. I have a question though, what does `flatten` actually do? Just wrap the integers into a single array?

Comment: The `flatten` docs I linked to will explain and demonstrate better than I can do in this comment :)